# Why take a lock the table at the fail in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I use a stored procedure and use autocommit ON in mysql v5.1.

```
 UPDATE client
 SET `status` = '0', withdraw_date = NOW()
 WHERE auth_token = p_auth_token;

 UPDATE order
 SET modate = NOW()
 WHERE client_auth_token = p_auth_token AND `status` = '0'; 
 //raise error no column client_auth_token 

 COMMIT;
```

When call the stored procedure, raise error because `client_auth_token` is not exist in order table. By the way, take record lock to client table. Why take the lock to client table not order table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the reserved word `order`. See [the list of reserved words in mysql 5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).
You need to use quotes around `order`, like you did for `status`. As per docs:

> Keywords and Reserved Words require special treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names.

```
UPDATE `order`
SET modate = NOW()
WHERE client_auth_token = p_auth_token AND `status` = '0';
```